# Convert & format list of arrays to tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of arrays that look like this:

```
c = [
 [
  [
    [670515.231, 6577538.931, 51.703], 
    [670486.853, 6577531.536, 51.703], 
    [670488.927, 6577523.577, 51.703], 
    [670517.305, 6577530.971, 51.703], 
    [670515.231, 6577538.931, 51.703]
  ]
 ]
]
```

And I would like to convert/format it to a tuple of array:s:

```
new_c =(
    [670515.231, 6577538.931, 51.703], 
    [670486.853, 6577531.536, 51.703], 
    [670488.927, 6577523.577, 51.703], 
    [670517.305, 6577530.971, 51.703], 
    [670515.231, 6577538.931, 51.703])
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: you want `tuple(c[0][0])`?

Comment: Just to clarify: technically these are lists not arrays. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> c = [
...  [
...   [
...     [670515.231, 6577538.931, 51.703],
...     [670486.853, 6577531.536, 51.703],
...     [670488.927, 6577523.577, 51.703],
...     [670517.305, 6577530.971, 51.703],
...     [670515.231, 6577538.931, 51.703]
...   ]
...  ]
... ]

>>> new_c = tuple(c[0][0])

>>> pprint(new_c)
([670515.231, 6577538.931, 51.703],
 [670486.853, 6577531.536, 51.703],
 [670488.927, 6577523.577, 51.703],
 [670517.305, 6577530.971, 51.703],
 [670515.231, 6577538.931, 51.703])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
c_tuple = tuple(c[0][0])
```

Or if the nesting depth of the list is different for each case:

```
tmp = c
while len(tmp) == 1:
    tmp = tmp[0]

c_tuple = tuple(tmp)
```